# How to set current date and end date based on subscription period?

Tags: java, jsp, date, servlets

I need to pass total months from JSP page to servlet and the servlet will set the starting date and ending date of subscription.

Suppose I passed 1 month from JSP page then servlet should able to add subscription date as current date and expiry date after 1 month into database.

I am using Oracle database and am not able to develop the logic for this. Please help me regarding this.

```
Date dNow = new Date( );
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("E yyyy.MM.dd 'at' hh:mm:ss a zzz");
String currentdate=ft.format(dNow);
String expirydate=ft.format(null);


Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
try {
    c.setTime(ft.parse(currentdate));
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, period_1);
    expirydate=ft.format(c.getTime());
}
catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code snippets of servlet as well JSP here by editing the question?

Comment: Please review: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: We are here to help you in problems, not develop code for you. Please first share what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly add no of month in sysdate in oracle insert query also.
ex. insert into abc(startdate,enddate) values(trunc(sysdate),TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(trunc(sysdate),12)));

you can develop java code also like

```
String dt = "2008-11-01";  
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(sdf.parse(dt));
    c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);  
    dt = sdf.format(c.getTime());  
    System.out.println(dt);
```